# Corner sink installation in corner lazy susan cabinets

Tags: kitchens, sink, installation

I need some opinions on how best to proceed with a corner sink installation. Our kitchen is a G shape, so we have two corner base cabinets. (Well, have one, will pick up another one tomorrow).

We are doing this on a very tight budget, so we purchased all our cabinets secondhand. The current corner cabinet we have has a lazy susan built in, but has square walls, as below:

[image]

The other one we may pick up tonight is the sort that has the cylindrical wall on the inside, like this:

[image]

So, two questions:

(1) Which base cabinet should I attempt to install the sink in? The first one with square walls is already installed in the corner that won't have the sink. The countertops are not yet attached, however, so I would need to unscrew it from the wall and the cabinets it's next to in order to use it as our sink base. Just would have to pop the cylindrical one in that space and re-level. The cylindrical one might be a bit more difficult to cut.

(2) Both have solid tops, so we'd have to cut the sink template in both the cabinet top and the countertop. How does one do this? Obviously I want to make sure that the cutouts line up, although at the very least the hole in the countertop has to be a better fit to the sink and the bottom one can have a bit bigger of an opening.

Comment: The sink in the corner sounds like a neat idea, though I have to ask: Have you made a template of the sink and set it on top of the corner cabinet, then stood there, hunched over, like you're doing the dishes or peeling carrots/potatoes for 10 minutes? Unless you have a square sink with a cut-out for the interior corner, that seems like an very awkward placement for usability.

Comment: From what you have written it kind of sounds like you are expecting to maintain the existing internal functionality of these corner cabinets. In order to accommodate the sink, water lines and drain lines you are going to have to completely gut the internals of those cabinets.

Comment: I have an existing corner sink and cabinet, so I know what to expect. Was just going to take out the lazy susan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use the square-walled for the sink, so you have more room to work with for pipes. And using the one with cylindrical walls as the main cabinet will help keep items from falling off the shelf into the nether regions the square corners would leave open.

Comment: Of course, I hadn't thought of that (drilling holes for the pipes). Been too obsessed with the sink part. That solves the first question, thanks Drew!

Answer (score 1):

Question 2: it's not clear to me what countertop material you're using, but if it's a normal postformed laminate type of top, then cut the counter accurately with a jigsaw, using the sink to get the size right. (Again, assumptions, but if it's a self-rimming sink, then you'll probably be around 1/2" in from the actual edge on the front and sides, and further in on the back.) Cut the holes for the faucet/etc with an appropriate size hole saw.

Once the countertop is scribed and placed on top of a permanently mounted cabinet, cut the hole in the top of the cabinet. Be aware of how the sink mounting brackets work and how much clearance/closeness they need.

Couple of minor tips for jigsawing laminate tops: if you can cut from the underside, then you won't run the risk of having the laminate flap and tear. (This happens when the laminate is imperfectly glued. To test, cut a bit in the middle of the waste section.) If you can't cut from the underside, "downcut" jigsaw blades are available. When you're about to finish the sink cutout, support the waste, so it doesn't fall and splinter the last little bit of the cut.

And my 2 cents worth on corner sinks... I liked the idea of them until I actually tried one. (Just my opinion, though.)

Comment: Thanks! We had an existing corner sink and like it, but to each their own. Very helpful :)